# Instantiating DateTime in PHP

Tags: php

Relatively little experience in PHP, but I've run into a parse error when trying to instantiate a new DateTime, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong!

The following results in a parse error:

```
public $date = new DateTime('now');
```

PHP version is 5.5.27

Comment: You can't define a property containing any value that requires run-time evaluation..... set the value in your constructor.... relevant quote from the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) - `This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated. `

Comment: Spot on, can't believe I didn't see that, thanks! - I had also not set the default timezone so had to add:
    `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');`
as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just leave out the argument to get the current date/time:

```
$date = new DateTime();
```

Comment: Turns out the reason the DateTime wasn't instantiating (apart from trying to instantiate in the wrong place) was that I hadn't set the default timezone, added that in and everything worked.

Comment: Please add that as an answer so that this question can be closed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the reason the DateTime wasn't instantiating (apart from trying to instantiate in the wrong place - thankyou Mark Baker) was that I hadn't set the default timezone, added that in and everything worked.